# ArgumentException thrown from Array.BinarySearch<T>(T[], int, int, T)

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

This [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kwds4b1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) page documents the method

```
public static int BinarySearch<T>(
    T[] array,
    int index,
    int length,
    T value
)
```

On the list of exceptions it states ArgumentException is thrown under the following circumstances:

> index and length do not specify a valid range in array.
>   -or- 
> value is of a type that is not compatible with the elements of array.

How is this possible? Under what circumstances can T not be compatible with an element from T[]? I suspect this might be an error in the documentation, or am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: I think documentation is wrong, it must be a `ctrl+c`, `ctrl+v` problem. I hope that was built over a non generic version of [binary search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksz8za9f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Looking at the decompiled source (4.5), I only see `if (array.Length - index < length) throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_InvalidOffLen"));`. Deeper calls seem to throw only `IndexOutOfRangeException` or `InvalidOperationException`, so it does look like the documentation is wrong. Also, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your question isn't about catching the exception - it's about whether the exception can ever be thrown.

Comment: [This is possible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664572%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) if the array element is an array, a problem induced by array covariance.

Comment: @HansPassant could you elaborate or perhaps answer the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [this link given above](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664572%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) I tried a few cases.

With this definition of Fill here:

```
public static void Fill(object[] array, int index, int count, object value)
    {
        for (int i = index; i < index + count; i++)
        {
            array[i] = value;
        }
    }
```

one can indeed get an `ArrayTypeMismatchException` on the third invocation here:

```
string[] strings = new string[100];
Fill(strings, 0, 100, "Undefined");
Fill(strings, 0, 10, null);
Fill(strings, 90, 10, 0); // a boxed 0 is not a string.
```

However, if I define Fill this way:
    public static void FillT(T[] array, int index, int count, T value)
        {
            for (int i = index; i < index + count; i++)
            {
                array[i] = value;
            }
        }

I *do not* get said exception because the following line doesn't even compile

```
FillT(strings, 90, 10, 0);
```

neither does this

```
FillT<string>(strings, 90, 10, 0);
```

So in this case, the compiler knows that the third argument must be of type string and an int cannot be passed there. Seems using generics helps avoiding nasty bugs in this scenario.

Comment: PMF thanks for replying. I marked this as a reply because it is the only reply (it *is* "the" reply) but I'm still looking for (one) proof that it is not possible or (two) demonstration of under what circumstances T would not be compatible with an element from T[].